# Twilio doesn't show the delivery status

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I have sent the SMS via laravel. In twilio delivery status not showing for that SMS. If I try to sent via Javascript it shows delivery status.

`$client->account->sms_messages->create($from, $sms_to, "Test SMS" , array());`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the code that creates the specific problem you are facing in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] of the site :)

Comment: Next to no information in the question to even start with help.  But those single quotes around the $from look suspect...  I would look at that first.

Comment: Yeah, the single quotes around `$from` are definitely going to break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are using the deprecated `SMS/Messages` endpoint with that call. The deprecated endpoint does not include delivery statuses.

Instead, you should call:

```
$client->account->messages->create($from, $sms_to, "Test SMS" , array());
```

Note that is `messages` not `sms_messages`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thnx...philnash

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the result to a variable, then, see what the method returns in order to print something.

```
$message = $client->account->sms_messages->create('$from', $sms_to, "Test SMS" , array());
print_r($message);
```

If you need further info, check the documentation and select your version: **https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/**